# Why sometimes, in threads, do you have to put sleep in a loop in the run method?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

Many times I have seen that in some sample solutions, if it said stop the thread every second, the creator did something like this, in the run method:

```
while(true){
    try{
       sleep(1000);
     }catch{...}
    //And following everything inside, what the run method should execute
}
```

So in a while loop that executes infinitely.
Otherwise, I have also seen this:

```
//codethat should be executed

try{
    sleep(1000);
}catch{...}
//(Without while loop, only in try catch block)
```

Why sometimes they put the sleep method in a loop, and sometimes not?

In some solutions, where the creator of the code put sleep in a loop and then I removed the loop, the code stopped working. In other cases where it was not in a loop, and I put it in a loop,  the code resulted in errors.... Why?

How can I know when I have to put it in a loop?

Comment: This is always going to depend on the "..." of what else is getting done.

Comment: In the catch they always have InterruptedException

Comment: Presumably there's other code that actually does something.

Comment: The downvotes are likely due to you not asking a *specific* question. You merely ask why someone would call the `sleep` method. Why do we call *any* method? To get its effects. If you want more explanation, you need to show some example code in a narrowly-focused context along with your specific thoughts or speculations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In these sample codes, `sleep` is mainly used to demonstrate a simulation who threads are working parallelly. If `sleep` is not used, then we won't be able differentiate if the code running in main thread or other thread.

Also putting the `sleep` inside makes the thread wait for 1 sec and executes the code thereafter for infinite period. The thread will not terminate and run for infinite period doing the same thing at regular interval. But when loop is not used, the code is only ran once and the thread waits for 1 sec and terminates. So it is mainly about the other piece of code doing.

Comment: I know, my problem is, how I know when I have to put the sleep in a loop, which are+ in the run method, and when its enough to put the sleep only in the run method?  For example I have see a game which was programmed also the creator puted sometimes sleep in a loop and sometimes not.

Comment: Well simply, putting the ```sleep``` inside makes the thread wait for 1 sec and executes the code thereafter for infinite period. The thread will not terminate and run for infinite period doing the same thing at regular interval. But when loop is not used, the code is only ran once and the thread waits for 1 sec and terminates. So it is mainly about the other piece of code doing.

Comment: okay but how do I know when I need the thread how often and accordingly put it in a loop or not?

Comment: Depends on the logic you are coding

Comment: You wait for 1 second if you write code that you want to wait 1 second.  That's all there is to it.  It's a bit like asking "when do I need to add 7?". There's no inherent reason in Java.

Comment: You should be aware that *sometimes*, adding a 'sleep' is a poor attempt to solve a concurrency problem without figuring out a proper solution.  But to determine that, one needs to see the entire code.